# jquery is not loading in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Now i have a requirement in jquery. But my jsp page not loading the jquery code. I am not able to address the issue.hereby i will give my code. can any one give suggestion on this?

My jsp is,

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="/css/stylesheets.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="/css/jquery_tzineClock.css" type="text/css">
    <script language="Javascript" src="/js/X2AUtils.js"> </script>
    <script language="Javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js"> </script>
    <script language="Javascript" src="/js/jquery_tzineClock.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" src="/js/counter.js"> </script>
    <script language="javascript">  

    </script>
</head>
<base target="_self">
<title></title>
<body>
<table width="1002" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="landingHdrBg" valign="top">
    <tr>    
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="98%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="bottom" >
                        <table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align = "right">
                        <tr>
                            <div id="fancyClock" > </div>
                             <p> sfgsdgsdgf</p>                                                 
                         </tr>

                        </table>
                     </td>
                   </tr>                               
        </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And my counter.js is,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */
    alert('On ready function');
    $("p").text = "testing.... ";
});
```

Here the alert is coming. but the para text is not changing . i downloaed various jquery.js and tried.

Comment: Triple nested [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/) layout tables? Oh dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have

```
$("p").html("testing....");

OR
$("p").text("testing....");
```

`.text()` should be a function that gets only the text without HTML tags. More information about text http://api.jquery.com/text/

Small fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gSc4z/

Comment: i tried with, html also it results same. i am using jsp page. Is any thing need to import?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#fancyClock').tzineClock();

});

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing the `alert`, then jQuery is loading fine.

The problem is your code changing the paragarph: You're setting a *property* called `text`, but [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a *function*, so you *call* it instead:

```
$("p").text("testing.... ");
```

Note that that line will change the text of *all* paragraphs to "testing.... ". Granted there's only one `p` element in your quoted markup, but presumably there will be more at some point...